# Can Most Beatles and Carpenters songs be played on a 61 key keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

I would like to know if there will be restriction in playing most of the Beatles and Carpenters songs on a 61 key keyboard due to limitation of the keys.

Comment: You can play any song in a Western key (no semitones) on any keyboard. It just takes a little arranging if you run out of octaves.  Same as a bass singer being able to sing a number written for a soprano.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - 'Western key', 'no semitones'? What's it mean?

Comment: @Tim - he probably means microtones used in other musical
 systems outside of the european tradition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microtonal_music : _Microtonal music or microtonality is the use in music of microtones—intervals smaller than a semitone, which are also called "microintervals". It may also be extended to include any music using intervals not found in the customary Western tuning of twelve equal intervals per octave..._

Comment: @Stinkfoot - it more than likely means almost the opposite - though when a question is asked, it's good to receive an answer. If he says 'you can play any song' that wouldn't include microtones. It *would* include diatonic notes, which comprise lots of pop type songs, although they can, and do modulate,. However, all normal keyboards are capable of coping with that, using the other five notes available. But 'Western key (no semitones)' seems to be an oxymoron.

Comment: @Tim _You can play any song in a Western key (no semitones) on any keyboard_  I think that means you can't play in an "in between" key.  For example, I believe there is an Indian or middle eastern system that divides an octave in 16 tones, instead of 12 - "microtones". You won't be able to play Paperback Writer in  that system in the key that comes after our G, "G 3/4#" for example, on our piano, which only supports 12 tones per octave, not the in between tones - "microtones" - relative to our twelve tone chromatic octave as represented on our piano. (You could conceivably play it on a violin)

Comment: @Stinkfoot - I've never noticed that Paperback Writer was anything but 'ordinary' notes. Just checked it out and it's a 3 chord trick. Probably in Mixolydian, but that still makes it playable on any keyboard.

Comment: @Tim - no argument - that's exactly what Paperback Writer is. I just took that as an example of a popular, simple Beatles song - same applies to everything, Beatles to Bach. Point is, if you wanted to change the key from G to "G + 3/4#"  (or something like that) - a note **between** G and G#  ( like when you bend on a guitar ) and play it on a piano - you couldn't, just like you can't really bend on a piano. But you could play that on certain instruments that use that 16 note scale - imagine you had a piano with 16 keys to span octave - or on a violin that allows you to play anything.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll be able to set a piano sound and play the printed song copies with little, if any, modification.  Or you could use more of the capabilities of a keyboard - maybe split the lower half to play a bass sound - and interpret the music more freely.

Answer (score 0):

Even though Karen Carpenter (still my most favourite) had a range of over four octaves, she didn't use it all in any song! Most songs that can be sung will have a range of a twelfth or so (octave and a half), leaving plenty of notes above and below to play the accompaniment.

So, yes, it's easily possible to do. Eventually you may feel the need to octave notes in the bass and top parts, but until you actually start doing that, 61 keys will suffice. It's five octaves in total, so even given the restriction of root notes/ highest tonic notes in some keys, it's plenty to go on. And, you'll find on a lot of keyboards with 61 notes, there is an octave button to go up or down 2 or 3 octaves, and coupled with a key change button, the range is as good as an 88 noter.

Answer (score 0):

I use a 61 key keyboard and am usually annoyed that it doesn't have ~5 more keys. That said, it's totally possible. You can play the song with probably even a 41 key keyboard, that doesn't mean you'll get the perfect balance of octaves, or any bass and treble mix at all. Replicating all of the songs by them perfectly on a 61 key keyboard probably can't be done unless you have really cool foot pedals, or a third hand and super high intellect.